# I will be uttering this with a moan

Tags: poetry, literature

What line is hidden behind the stars?

> I will be uttering this with a moan
>   someplace aeons and aeons therefore:
>   $*****$ $*****$ $*****$ $*****$
>   and I picked up the one with inferior migration,
>   And this has caused complete disagreement

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks  for this.

> The Path Not Taken by Robert Frost.
>
>  I shall be telling this with a sigh
>  Somewhere, ages and ages hence:
>  **Two roads diverged in a wood and I,**
>  I took the one less traveled by
>  And that has made all the difference. 
>
>
>  Much as I hate to add to or subtract from the verse above, @BigBlackBox and @LightnessRacesInOrbit have a point and an obscured line ought really to be part of an accepted answer. Any upvotes therefore properly belong to him. Technically, there should also be an explanation of the reasoning as well but there is pretty much a one-to-one mapping between the original and the obscured version. So:
>
>  **A thoroughfare bifurcated in a copse and, myself-**

Comment: You don't seem to have answered the question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's the middle line

Comment: @Hu​​​​​​​​​​​​gh: Is it? You quoted the original poem. Do you not need to produce some synonyms for the middle line in order to answer the question? At the very least, some explanation of why you think quoting the poem satisfies the question would be great.

Answer (score 6):

The line is

> A pair of highways uncoupled in a hard fibrous material, and I-

because

> As Hugh Meyers' answer explains, the poem is an encoded version of the last stanza of The Road Not Taken by Robert Frost. The hidden third line asked for by OP therefore should be an *encoded* version of the third line
>
>  *Two roads diverged in a wood, and I-*
>
>  from that stanza, and not the original line as Hugh Meyers' solution claims.