# What is missing?

Tags: poetry, literature

I don't know how classy it is to design a puzzle of exactly the same type as [one already posted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30711/i-will-be-uttering-this-with-a-moan). Feel free to delete if you think it's unfair. But they say that imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, so here goes:

> despite how narrow the entrance is
>   or how bad my rap sheet is
>   ?????????????????????????
>   I am in charge of my heart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like

> Invictus by Henley
>  It matters not how strait the gate
>  How charged with punishments the scroll
>  I am the master of my fate
>  I am the captain of my soul